# Lower bound for chromatic number of a regular graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

In a certain exercise I am asked to show that if $G$ is a $k$-regular graph, then $\chi(G) \geq \frac{n}{n-k}$, where $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$. As far as I have reached, I know that in a coloring of $G$ using the least colors possible, we can classify the vertices on sets $C_i = \{ v \in V(G): color(v) = i \}$. It is clear that, if we use a number of colors equal to the chromatic number, this classification of vertices in sets form a partition, and there cannot be edges between vertices of the same set, and there must be at least an edge from $C_i$ to $C_j$ if $i \not = j$. I also noticed that $\frac{n}{n-k} = 1 + \frac{k}{n-k}$. Could somebody give a hint to show the inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

If $G$ is a regular graph of degree $k$, then $\bar G$ is a regular graph of degree $n-k-1$.
Since $\omega(G)=\alpha(\bar G)$, $\alpha(\bar G)\geq \frac{n}{n-k}$, and $\chi(G)\geq \omega(G)$ it follows that $\omega(G)\geq \frac{n}{n-k}$.

**Addition.**
If $G$ is a graph, then

1. $\bar{G}$ is the complement of $G$;
2. $\alpha(G)$ is the independence number of $G$, that is, the size of the independent set of largest possible size of $G$;
3. the clique number $\omega(G)$ of the graph $G$ is the number of vertices in a maximum clique in $G$.

Comment: I guess that $G$ with a line above is the complementary graph, right? By the way, could you explain me your notation?

Comment: @DanielC., Thank you. I have supplemented my answer and will be happy to answer all your questions.